# making grinder work with jython

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic, jython, grinder

I have a java class for starting the server on ActiveMQ and I want to hook up grinder with the JMS messaging, so I am writing a client code in jython with Grinder. When I run the server and try to send a message from my jython client, I get the following error:

```
2013-09-16 12:38:40,802 INFO  home-0 : The Grinder version 3.11
2013-09-16 12:38:40,807 INFO  home-0 : Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 1.7.0_25-b15: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (23.25-b01, mixed mode) on Mac OS X x86_64 10.8.3
2013-09-16 12:38:40,810 INFO  home-0 : time zone is EDT (-0400)
2013-09-16 12:38:40,887 INFO  home-0 : worker process 0
2013-09-16 12:38:40,933 INFO  home-0 : instrumentation agents: byte code transforming instrumenter for Jython 2.5; byte code transforming instrumenter for Java
2013-09-16 12:38:43,771 INFO  home-0 : running "http.py" using Jython 2.5.2 (Release_2_5_2:7206, Mar 2 2011, 23:12:06) 
[Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (Oracle Corporation)]
2013-09-16 12:38:43,814 ERROR home-0 thread-0: aborting thread - {}The result of 'TestRunner()' is not callable
net.grinder.scriptengine.jython.JythonScriptExecutionException: The result of 'TestRunner()' is not callable
    at net.grinder.scriptengine.jython.JythonScriptEngine.createWorkerRunnable(JythonScriptEngine.java:183) ~[grinder-core-3.11.jar:na]
    at net.grinder.engine.process.GrinderProcess$ThreadStarterImplementation$2.create(GrinderProcess.java:784) ~[grinder-core-3.11.jar:na]
    at net.grinder.engine.process.GrinderThread.run(GrinderThread.java:90) ~[grinder-core-3.11.jar:na]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
2013-09-16 12:38:43,814 INFO  home-0 : start time is 1379349523814 ms since Epoch
2013-09-16 12:38:43,817 INFO  home-0 : elapsed time is 3 ms
2013-09-16 12:38:43,817 INFO  home-0 : Final statistics for this process:
2013-09-16 12:38:43,823 INFO  home-0 : 
             Tests        Errors       Mean Test    Test Time    TPS          
                                       Time (ms)    Standard                  
                                                    Deviation                 
                                                    (ms)                      
Totals       0            0            -            0.00         0.00         
  Tests resulting in error only contribute to the Errors column.          
  Statistics for individual tests can be found in the data file, including
  (possibly incomplete) statistics for erroneous tests. Composite tests   
  are marked with () and not included in the totals.
```

my client code is a below:

```
from net.grinder.script.Grinder import grinder
from net.grinder.script import Test


from com.droitfintech.core.jms.factory import JMSBuilderFactory

log=grinder.logger
test1=Test(1,"Log method")
test1.record(log)

class TestRunner:
    def _call_(self):
        log=grinder.logger.info
        log("Creating queue session")
        messageQueueName="InputQueue"

        fileName=open('basis_USD3s6s.xml','r+').read()


        print fileName    
        newInstance=JMSBuilderFactory.getInstance()
        newInstance.getConnector().sendMessage(messageQueueName,fileName)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rename your `_call_` method to `__call__`